# Avoid second row moving to next line on smaller screens Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I've got an issue here that I can't quite get my head round.

I have 2 rows of 3 images.  What I want is on screens 841px and lower, the columns should be 50% - this works fine however as they are rows of 3, on mobile I have 2-1 and 2-1. The second row starts on a new line which probably is meant to happen but the questions is how to avoid it?

I've set up a jsfiddle to show you what I mean. I want image 4 to fill that gap on the right of 3 so that all images go in a continuous order without any gaps. I tried floating the images to left to see if that pulled it up but no luck.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/97v6aktj/)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/hm1cb910x/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/f5zixeiy9/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/aldcigz8x/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/kjyb4y8oh/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/duwd2ocq9/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/o68pvc4fl/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.margin-bottom {
padding-bottom:20px;
}

@media (max-width: 841px) {
.col-xs-4 {
width:50%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 511px) {
.col-xs-4 {
width:100%;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97v6aktj/3/)

> this is the situation you need to use more than one column class
>   together.

accoroding to screen for screen

`xs` works on mobile device.

`sm` small device eg tablet.

`md` medium devices

`lg` large desktops

**i advice you to remove your custom css codes.**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/o68pvc4fl/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
 </div>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Boostrap they are having separate classes in grid system, for every devices [GRID SYSTEM FOR Mobile, tablet, desktop](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete). `col-xs` for extra small devices, `col-md` for medium devices, `col-sm` for small devices.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97v6aktj/1/)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/hm1cb910x/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
   </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/f5zixeiy9/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/aldcigz8x/image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive margin-bottom"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

No in x-small screens all your image section take full row, small screen it takes 2 in a row other one is wrapped and in medium 3 in a row.