# How to make items stay in line even on smaller devices with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having troubles. I am making a website with bootstrap. When I make an a row with bootstrap and add my columns, the different columns go to a new line under each other when the devices shrink in size..

my code is as follow

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><center>Feed</center></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><center>Tutor</center></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><center>Profile</center></div>
</div>
```

im not sure what i am doing wrong. Everytime i shrink my browser, it stills shrink into a new line. Help please!

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap version 4

Comment: Check your bootstrap versions or there is other div's with `row`?

Comment: No , its no other divs inside the row. The CDN says "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js".... when i click inspect and look at the mobile device, it don't look like it goes down to a new line. but if i manually shrink the screen, the items does go down when the window gets really small in width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid second row moving to next line on smaller screens Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264947/avoid-second-row-moving-to-next-line-on-smaller-screens-bootstrap-3)

Comment: I looked at that as well. I dont have any custom code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply below css either through class name to parent row, or direct styling

```
.cls_name{
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

here nowrap will forcefully show all child in a single row

Comment: i dont understand exactly what this did, but it worked! thanks! Mind explaining why this worked? I used direct styling ** I dont really like using things that i cant explain to myself**

Comment: The flexwrap property will specify whether the items in given flex (its children) shoud wrap(height flexible based on size and content) or not (all child should be in same line) .  For more info you can visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will help you.

```css
.single-row{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row single-row" >
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">Feed</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">tutor</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">profile</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so i dont use the row div? nor the col for the ms and xs? also don't it have to equal 12? sorry im kind of new to bootstrap.

Comment: This is using bootstrap 3. Just check the bootstrap 4 classes to know more about the Bootstrap 4 https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp